# Entity Framework Code first cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-relations

We have a database that is creating some multiple cascade paths errors.
I do understand what that means and what is happening, but I'd like to know the best approach since we have to remove some of the OnDelete Cascade options we have.

This is our table structure:

```
SCHOOL
- SchoolId  
- Name
- ....

STUDENT
- StudentId
- SchoolId
- Name
- ...

COURSE
- CourseId
- SchoolId
- Name

STUDENT-COURSE
- StudentId
- CourseId
- ....
```

- SchoolId FK in Student deletes all the students related in cascade when deleting a school
- SchoolId FK in Course deletes all the courses related in cascade when deleting a school
- StudentId FK in Student-Course deletes all the student-courses related in cascade when deleting a student
- CourseId FK in Student-Course deletes all the student-courses related in cascade when deleting a course

So here we have the cycle, because when deleting a school the entity Student-Course is going to be deleted from 2 different sides, creating the cycle.

I understand what happens here:

```
HasMany(p => p.Students)
   .WithRequired(p => p.School)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.SchoolId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And I know I can do:

```
HasMany(p => p.Students)
    .WithRequired(p => p.School)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.SchoolId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The question here is what would be the best approach.

Thanks.

Comment: There are probably more students than courses, so cascaded delete of students + studentcourses is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove on delete cascade from the School, and leave the others as is, and when deleting a school add some logic to delete related students, courses (but his keeps a consistency for deletes in lower levels).
If you remove on delete cascade from the Students, you will need to manually add deletion logic for them to clean related student courses first, and will be somehow inconsistent with courses delete (hierarchical level is not consistent in terms of deletion logic).

Comment: That sound good, so remove from upper levels and do some logic in code for those levels. This way lower levels don't need logic. Thanks !!!